# Are there numerical differences between classical and quantum solutions of problems such as the Born-Jordan quantization?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

Consider an implementation of the Born-Jordan quantization or an arbitrary Cohen class time-frequency analysis algorithm.

Are there any numerical differences between classical and quantum solutions? Would our visualizations of the data output change in any way? (Or perhaps, would we have to change the way we visualize the data?)